# how to get Twitter user image in android

Tags: android, twitter

I am unable to get the Twitter user image.
I got the user name and user id like this:

```
Twitter mTwitter = TwitterUtil.getInstance().getTwitter();
String userid = mTwitter.getId();
String username= mTwitter.getScreenName();
```

For the image I tried:

```
String image = mTwitter.getUserProfileImage();
```

But this method is not working.
Please help me to get the user image.

Comment: Try mTwitter.getProfileImageURL();

Comment: Kaustav Ghosh brother ,, this code is not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
User user = twitter.showUser(twitter.getScreenName());
String profileImage = user.getProfileImageURL();
System.out.println("Profile Image URL : " +profileImage);
```

Output :

```
Profile Image URL : http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/435454y55465/AQRi1ZjC_normal.jpeg
```

Tip : `twitter.getScreenName()` returns the logined handleName and we add that paramter into `showUser` method. If you want to try for other user, pass their screenName or ID.

Comment: yeah,, sorry,, forgot  :)